# Cannot use WITH statement two times

Tags: sql-server, database, common-table-expression

I wan't to create a view that is constructed like this:
(simplified)

```
Create VIEW viewAll AS
With TempLevel1 AS
```

(
*`SELECT statement`*
)

```
With TempLevel2 AS (SELECT * from TempLevel1)

SELECT * from TempLevel2
```

The problem is that I cannot use With statement like this because of
the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'With'.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
>
> If this statement is a
>   common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
>   context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.

I have to specify that the SELECT queries are way more complex and I do have to use With two times.

Would it be a better practice to create the first with statement as another view like viewTempLevel1 (and use it in the With TempLevel2 statement)?

Comment: There're many statements you can't use twice, such as `SELECT`, `FROM` or `WHERE`. In such cases, they sometimes just accept several parameters.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález that's not the case here though. The *keyword* doesn't need to be repeated to specify multiple CTEs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It doesn't? I'd say it cannot. You've even posted it as answer so I guess I've been misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql#examples) for Common table Expressions (**CTE**), you can

> Use a comma to separate multiple CTE definitions

Example is (taken straight out of the docs)

```
WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, TotalSales, SalesYear)  
AS  
-- Define the first CTE query.  
(  
    SELECT SalesPersonID, SUM(TotalDue) AS TotalSales, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear  
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader  
    WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL  
       GROUP BY SalesPersonID, YEAR(OrderDate)  

)  
,   -- Use a comma to separate multiple CTE definitions.  

-- Define the second CTE query, which returns sales quota data by year for each sales person.  
Sales_Quota_CTE (BusinessEntityID, SalesQuota, SalesQuotaYear)  
AS  
(  
       SELECT BusinessEntityID, SUM(SalesQuota)AS SalesQuota, YEAR(QuotaDate) AS SalesQuotaYear  
       FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory  
       GROUP BY BusinessEntityID, YEAR(QuotaDate)  
)  

-- Define the outer query by referencing columns from both CTEs.  
SELECT SalesPersonID...
```

In your case, the syntax would be...

```
With TempLevel1 AS
    ( SELECT statement [...]), 
TempLevel2 AS 
    (SELECT * from TempLevel1)

SELECT * from TempLevel2
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to repeat the `WITH` keyword. Separate the CTE expressions by comma:

```
With CTE_Level1 AS
( 
    SELECT statement 
),
CTE_Level2 AS 
(
    SELECT * from CTE_Level1
)
SELECT * from CTE_Level2
```